# Where QGIS puts my downloaded Crayfish plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

I just downloaded the Crayfish plugin. It downloaded successfully but then when I search for it in QGIS, it is nowhere to be found. Can someone suggest where it might be located?

Comment: It should be under View>Panels [Crayfish 2D Plot]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

After installing the "Crayfish" Plugin in QGIS it should appear in the Mesh menu

[image: mesh_menu]

Moreover, as was already mentioned by @Mapperz a Crayfish 2D Plot is available via `RMC > Panels > Crayfish 2D Plot`

[image: 2d_Plot]

You can also find "Crayfish" in the Processing Toolbox

[image: toolbox]

For more details please check [the official documentation](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/projects/crayfish/).

Comment: The plot option is also available, by the context menu: when right-clicking on a mesh layer from layers panel.